# Overloading generic type parameters disallowed?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, clr

It's part curiosity and part because I was just trying to use this. If you have the following definitions, this is not allowed by the compiler because it says that the member is already defined. What's the reasoning behind not allowing exclusive overloads of generic type parameters?

```
void Get<T>() where T: struct {}
void Get<T>() where T: class {}
```

It seems to me that there's no inherent problem with this. One might argue that it is not always clear which the compiler should choose in cases where the definitions overlap (but a common resolution seems to be most specific match first).

Can someone help me understand  or point to a resource what the reasoning is behind disallowing this?

Comment: Out of interest, what kind of thing was your actual use case trying to do?

Comment: @AakashM: simple, I needed to convert nullable types in a different way than non-nullable value types. I thought a generic overload was a quick way to fix it. The method takes an object and a type param and I cannot restrict the type param (well, I can, but I cannot overload it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eric Lippert already answered this one, in a blog post on generic constraints and method signatures: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Constraints on generic types are not part of method signatures in the CLR, therefore you can't have two methods that differ only in generic type constraints. Without CLR support it would be quite fiddly to get C# to support these in a sensible fashion that is compatible with other .NET languages.

Comment: If you state it that way, it seems logical. One can only wonder, _why_ isn't it made part of the method signature? Did Anders Hejlsberg have a good reason for not designing it any other way? Didn't fully read Lippert's article yet. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: My guess is that it's a CLR limitation - the CLR also doesn't consider generic type constraints part of a method signature. There's no way to represent generic constraints in the binary representation of method signatures, so it's quite a deep limitation.

Comment: @Abel: thecoop is correct; this is a limitation of the CLR. We could of course in theory make constraints a part of the signature, which would certainly be helpful in your specific case. But in the general case, it presents a lot of problems. For example: `void M<T>() where T : IFoo {}` and `void M<T>() where T : IBar {}` would be different method signatures; so what method is `M<Blah>` where `Blah` is a class that implements both `IFoo` and `IBar`? The rules to deal with ambiguous signatures are complicated enough already; let's not add a whole new host of ways to be ambiguous.

Comment: @EricLippert / thecoop: I would suggest simply to allow the same overloading rules as with normal method overloading. I.e. having `void F(IComparable x){}` and `void F(IConvertible x) {}`, then calling `int i; F(i);` will throw a compile time error "Ambiguous invocation". I don't see why not the same semantics could be used with type params (but I'm often accused in W3 standardization discussions that I oversimplify things a bit).

Comment: @Abel: The overloading rules don't matter. The difference between your two `Get` methods cannot be expressed in two different method signatures that allow them to be identified unambiguously in the metadata of an assembly in the current version of the CLR. Adding generic constraints to method signatures would be a significant change in the core of the CLR that is highly unlikely to happen anytime soon, if at all.

Comment: I understand that is currently cannot be done, and probably will never be done. I was merely arguing in the context of "what if" (Futile, perhaps, but it exercises the mind and helps understanding things). There's no need to change the CLR for that, as Eric Lippert points out. But IL generation will change significantly regardless, so I second that it's highly unlikely to ever happen ;).

Answer (score 1):

The `struct` constraint on `Nullable<T>` is IMHO really unfortunate.  Something like a `Nullable<String>` or a `Nullable<Nullable<Nullable<int>>>` might be have wasteful, but so what?  Box the former as its content; unbox it as its content and set the `HasValue` if the content is non-null.  Box the former as an `int` if all of the nullables report `HasValue`, and when unboxing, set `HasValue` of all nested items if the content was non-null.

Otherwise, I would suggest that you create a static generic class with type parameter `T` which contains a delegate property that accepts a `T` as a parameter.  The property should return the content of a private field which should be initialized to point to a method that will check the type of `T` and set the delegate to either the `struct` or `class` version as appropriate.

Here's a sample of what I'm talking about; this one uses various interface constraints rather than struct/class constraints, but the same principles can be used just as effectively.

```
        static class _FooDispatcher<T>
        {
            public static Action<T> Foo = setupFoo;

            static void doFooWithIGoodFoo<TT>(TT param) where TT : IGoodFoo
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dispatching as IGoodFoo with {1} type {0}", typeof(TT).ToString(), typeof(TT).IsValueType ? "value" : "reference");
                param.Foo();
            }
            static void doFooWithIOkayFoo<TT>(TT param) where TT : IOkayFoo
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dispatching as IOkayFoo with {1} type {0}", typeof(TT).ToString(), typeof(TT).IsValueType ? "value" : "reference");
                param.Foo();
            }
            static void doFooSomehow<TT>(TT param)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing exciting with {1} type {0}", typeof(TT).ToString(), typeof(TT).IsValueType ? "value" : "reference");
            }
            static void setupFoo(T param)
            {
                System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi;
                if (typeof(IGoodFoo).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
                    mi = typeof(_FooDispatcher<T>).GetMethod("doFooWithIGoodFoo", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
                else if (typeof(IOkayFoo).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
                    mi = typeof(_FooDispatcher<T>).GetMethod("doFooWithIOkayFoo", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
                else
                    mi = typeof(_FooDispatcher<T>).GetMethod("doFooSomehow", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
                Foo = (Action<T>)(@Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>), mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T))));
                Foo(param);
            }
        }
```